# Ask twilio if a specific client is connected?

Tags: twilio

Can i ask twilio if a specific client is present -connected- or not without using Twilio presence event handler ? is there some api like client(name).present? predicate

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately today there is no way to ask Twilio if a specific client is connected.  The only way to know when a client comes online or goes offline is to listen to the presence event handler.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#presence

Please note this method has been deprecated in version 1.3 of twilio.js.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this still the case? If so, how would you recommend keeping track of who's logged into a call center type web application/client? If this is too broad or been answered elsewhere, please point me in a direction via link to docs/solution (if known). Thanks.

Comment: Hey Jim, I'd suggest checking out TaskRouter which makes this a lot easier.  https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter